# Dynamically Assigning a Data type C++

Tags: c++, class, types, instantiation

Is there a way I can write a data type into a string, and then instantiate the type from the string.

I have a map editor that creates a map of definitions (i.e: "aa" = sand tile, "ab" = grass tile), but it would be convenient, if instead of having a hefty switch statement, I could just access the definition of a tile (i.e: I pass in "aa" and receive a sand tile) and then directly instantiating the sand tile. Here's some pseudo-code in case I'm being too vague.

instead of:

(The following pseudo-code snippets are assuming all tiles inherit from some sort of tile class that has a constructor which takes in an x and y value.)

```
switch definitions[tileType]{
 case "sandTile":
  sandTile tile(x,y);
  break;
 case "grassTile":
  grassTile tile(x,y);
  break;
 case "waterTile":
  waterTile tile(x,y);
  break;
```

Something like

```
string type = declarations[tileType];
magicalDataTypeCaster<type> tile(x,y);
```

Thanks for reading!

Comment: No reflection in C++, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply have a map from the tile type string to a function that takes x and y arguments and returns a pointer to the common tile base class...

```
typedef Tile* (*Creator)(X x, Y y);
std::map<std::string, Creator> creators;
creators["sandTile"] = &SandTile::create;  // static Creator

....

Tile* a_tile = creators[type](x, y);
```

Comment: I'm sorry but, for my sake, could you dumb that down a tad..?

Do you mean like, defining a map where the key is a string, but the element is a data type?

Comment: The element is a pointer to a function specific to the derived type the key identifies, and that function returns a pointer to a newly allocated/constructed instance of that derived class.

Comment: How would I store a pointer in a file that is premade?

As it stands, the file pretty much would read something like this in the header:

"aa" = (grassTile, goblinEnemy)

EDIT: Sorry, I didn't see your edit until after I commented

Comment: No worries - added the example because it sounded like you'd want it ;-).  By the way - this kind of thing is known as a factory pattern... if you Google that you'll find masses of examples and explanations.